# Lateral Thinking -> Brainteaser

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Since they're so much alike (See; [What exactly is the point of lateral-thinking?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-lateral-thinking)) I suggested a tag not to long ago but it still didn't get much attention. So now **I'm coming right out and begging for people to look at it!**

You can find it here; https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/lateral-thinking/synonyms

*For more details view the link stated above*